# Non Responsive Bulma Nav

Tags: bulma

I am using Bulma, I have a need to make the navigation bar, non responsive. I do not want the hamburger menu or the collapsed nav.

I cannot work out how to do this though, there is no mention in the docs.

Bootstrap had a class you could add that would support this, is it possible with Bulma?

Comment: Can you please show us what have you tried so far and which class in bootstrap support the nav feature ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/), `.navbar-menu` is the class responsible for hiding the navigation bar on mobile.  One solution would be to not use that class.  Many Bulma items, like the nav bar, have elements that are optional.  You may omit the `.navbar-menu` and `.navbar-burger` elements and it will still work.  See example below.

If you have navigation elements that are dropdowns, you may have to write a bit of CSS to correct it for mobile.  Otherwise look into using the dropdown component: https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
        </a>

        
      
          <a class="navbar-item">
            Home
          </a>

          <a class="navbar-item">
            Documentation
          </a>

    </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am aware of, there isn't an inbuilt class to handle this. However, according to the [docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/) when you installed bulma you could set the $navbar-breakpoint which is what is responsible for collapsing the nav into a hamburger. Not a great solution since it requires a reinstall.

So that said, you will probably want to make your own class that will handle the display with [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the sass variables.

```
$navbar-breakpoint:0;
```